# Is there a way to know who bought my books on Amazon?

Tags: self-publishing

I self-published some books on Amazon. I find it frustrating that I cannot contact my customers to ask for feedback on the books / ask them if they are interested in further products and use the book as a way to build a community.

Is there a way to track who buys your book on Amazon or to reach out to people buying my books?

Comment: Tracking purchases; I'd contact Amazon. As a self published author you'll need to generate an audience yourself so social media is vital. And through social media you can reach out to your readers.

Comment: Having bought a book on Amazon, I would hate it if the author was given my email address. I would consider it a violation of privacy.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no way to track who buys your books on Amazon.

In your books, give readers a way to connect with you. Links to your book/author/publisher web site. Link to a mailing list. Links to your social media accounts. An offer that they can sign up for (a free ebook version of the print book they bought, or a discount on another book, or a free short story with the same characters, or ...).

The readers who want you to contact them will follow those links and connect with you.

Any buyer who does not connect is not interested in hearing from you… right now. Respect that. They will reach out to you when they are ready.

Comment: The nature of my books at the moment is quite hobby interest with usually a fair few questions about technical kit, tips and advice. Thanks I will try what you say.

Comment: Worth noting that you can make these changes in the book *retroactively* -- when you re-upload (and Amazon gets through with their internal processing), it'll be pushed out to all devices it was previously downloaded on.  This feature is usually used to correct errata, but can be used to add content like a foreword, afterword, etc.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Ugh. That's a nice reminder that we never truly own ebooks :(